# How can I substitute just the last occurrence of -) in a string using sed, bash or awk?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Example input file:

```
xxx-xxx(-)        xxx   xxx  xxx      -       2e-15   Cytochrome b-c1 complex subunit 9       xxx   xxx:241-77(-)
xxx-xxx(+)        xxx   xxx  xxx      +       3e-24   Probable endo-beta-1,4-glucanase D       xxx   xxx:241-77(+)
```

I've been trying sed, but without success. I can see that the following two things work:

```
rev file|sed -e 's/-/M/'|rev
rev file|sed -e 's/)/M/'|rev
```

But, `-` and `)` together do not work:

```
rev file|sed -e 's/-)/M/'|rev
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `rev` "reverses" the order, you know? `-)` does not occur in the reversed version; it is `)-` in the reversed file:

```
rev file|sed -e 's/)-/M/'|rev
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need multiple commands with chains of pipes or fancy operations - since seds regexps are greedy, all you need is:

```
$ sed 's/\(.*\)-)/\1M/' file
xxx-xxx(-)        xxx   xxx  xxx      -       2e-15   Cytochrome b-c1 complex subunit 9       xxx   xxx:241-77(M
xxx-xxx(+)        xxx   xxx  xxx      +       3e-24   Probable endo-beta-1,4-glucanase D       xxx   xxx:241-77(+)
```

Comment: Why is replacing the first one hard? Wouldn't `sed 's/-)/M/' file` to the trick?

Answer (score 0):

#### A general approach for "replace the *n*th-to-last one of something" with pure (GNU) sed

1. We want to replace "something", in this case `-)`, with something unique not found elsewhere in your input, say `~B`. To make sure that this sequence isn't in your input, we first replace all `~` with `~A`:

   ```
   sed 's/~/~A/g' infile
   ```
2. Replace all "something", in this case `-)`, with `~B`, of which we now know that it'll be unique:

   ```
   sed 's/-)/~B/g'
   ```

   Now your input file looks like this (slightly edited so it fits the line width here):

   ```
   xxx-xxx(~B  xxx   -   2e-15   Cytochrome b-c1 complex subunit 9   xxx   xxx:241-77(~B
   xxx-xxx(+)  xxx   +   3e-24   Probable endo-beta-1,4-glucanase D   xxx   xxx:241-77(+)
   ```
3. The next command does this: "as longs as the line has *n* + 1 of `~B`, replace the first one with `-)`. The `:a` and `ta` are a label to branch to and conditional branching ("go to label `:a` if a substitution took place"):

   ```
   sed ':a;/~B\(.*~B\)\{1\}/s/~B/-)/;ta'
   ```

   For the case of *n* = 1, i.e., we want to replace the last occurrences, the quantifier `\{1\}` is of course not needed, but can be replaced for other values of *n*.

   The input file now has a unique `~B` where the last `-)` used to be:

   ```
   xxx-xxx(-)  xxx   -   2e-15   Cytochrome b-c1 complex subunit 9   xxx   xxx:241-77(~B
   xxx-xxx(+)  xxx   +   3e-24   Probable endo-beta-1,4-glucanase D   xxx   xxx:241-77(+)
   ```
4. We replace that single `~B`:

   ```
   sed 's/~B/M/'
   ```

   resulting in

   ```
   xxx-xxx(-)  xxx   -   2e-15   Cytochrome b-c1 complex subunit 9   xxx   xxx:241-77(M
   xxx-xxx(+)  xxx   +   3e-24   Probable endo-beta-1,4-glucanase D   xxx   xxx:241-77(+)
   ```
5. The rest of the `~B` can now be replaced with what they were, `-)` (a no-op in this case):

   ```
   sed 's/~B/-)/g'
   ```
6. Finally, we undo the first substitution (which has no effect for this example as the input had no `~` to start with):

   ```
   sed 's/~A/~/g'
   ```

All in a single line:

```
sed 's/~/~A/g;s/-)/~B/g;:a;/~B\(.*~B\)\{1\}/s/~B/-)/;ta;s/~B/M/;s/~B/-)/g;s/~A/~/g' infile
```

Or, for readability, over multiple lines:

```
sed '
s/~/~A/g
s/-)/~B/g
:label
/~B\(.*~B\)\{1\}/s/~B/-)/
t label
s/~B/M/
s/~B/-)/g
s/~A/~/g
' infile
```

Naturally, for the case of *n* = 1, there are much simpler solutions, like [Ed Morton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35676369/3266847).

Comment: FYI rather than trying to guess at a 2-character string that doesn't exist in the file, you can create one like this: `sed 's/~/~A/g; s/-)/~B/g; <whatever>; s/~B/-)/g; s/~A/~/g'`. The first subsitution makes sure that every `~` in the input file is now succeeded by `A` so that the string `~B` (instead of your `~~` - I haven't convinced myself this approach works if you repeat a char) CANNOT now be present in the input file and the last substitution unwinds that again after you've done all of your operations on it..

Comment: I don't see why any of that's necessary for this though - you're changing a 2 char string `-)` to another 2-char string `~~` - why not skip that and just do all of your subsequent operations on `-)` instead of `~~`?

Comment: @EdMorton Your answer is of course much, much more elegant. The reason for changing the string to another string first is to change all except the last one of them back to the original string so we have our `~~` where we want to replace the original string - I don't see how you can do that directly on the original string.

Comment: @EdMorton Added the guaranteed uniqueness thing. This whole answer now looks rather stupid, seeing how simple it could have been done...